# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception

Tags: zend-framework

I am getting following error after configuring following error.

http://www.iprogrammerindia.in/crud-operations-zend-framework-2/

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\InvalidServiceNameException'
  with message 'An alias by the name "translator" or "translator" already exists'
  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/crudapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:822

Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/crudapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/Config.php(149): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->setAlias('translator', 'MvcTranslator')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/crudapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ServiceListener.php(222): Zend\ServiceManager\Config->configureServiceManager(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager))
#2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->onLoadModulesPost(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/crudapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/crudapp in /opt/lampp/htdocs/crudapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 822
```

Answer (score 0):

`ZendSkeletonApplication` already [defines translator as a factory](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/2c9e759f873b7763c4437c019d45b780dbc6fefb/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L63):

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
    ),
),
```

Same service can not be defined as an alias and as a factory at the same time.

Tutorial you linked is for an older `ZendSkeletonApplication`, which defined translator as an alias.
Alias can override alias on configuration merge, so it didn't cause any errors.

To fix the issue, remove `translator` alias declaration from `module\Admin\config\module.config.php`